# REACT: How do I map through array of objects, then onclick add an individually to another array in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont know how to add to the new array individually using the key of the element. I have state set up here with a function to the new array `onclick`:

```
this.state = {
  applications: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John Smith",
      position: "Server",
      applied: "03/15/16",
      experience: 2,
      availability: {
        M: 2,
        T: 2,
        W: 1,
        Th: 2,
        F: 1,
        S: 0,
        Su: 0
      },
      questions: [
        {
          text: "Have you ever been convicted of a felony?",
          answer: "No"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Jane Smith",
      position: "Cook",
      applied: "02/08/16",
      experience: 4,
      availability: {
        M: 1,
        T: 1,
        W: 1,
        Th: 1,
        F: 0,
        S: 0,
        Su: 0
      },
      questions: [
        {
          text: "Have you ever been convicted of a felony?",
          answer: "Yes"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "David Jessup",
      position: "Chef",
      applied: "03/08/16",
      experience: 2,
      availability: {
        M: 2,
        T: 2,
        W: 2,
        Th: 2,
        F: 2,
        S: 0,
        Su: 0
      },
      questions: [
        {
          text: "Are you authorized to work in the United States?",
          answer: "Yes"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Clay vanSchalkwijk",
      position: "Cook",
      applied: "03/08/16",
      experience: 1,
      availability: {
        M: 1,
        T: 0,
        W: 1,
        Th: 0,
        F: 1,
        S: 0,
        Su: 0
      },
      questions: [
        {
          text: "Are you authorized to work in the United States?",
          answer: "Yes"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  saved: []
};
```

This is the function I want to run:

```
onFavorite = savedApp =>
  this.setState({
    saved: [...this.state.saved, savedApp]
  });
```

Here I want to click favourite then have it run the function and add to the new array (by the key ID):

```
render() {
  const all_applications = this.state.applications.map(function(elem) {
    return (
      <li key={elem.id}>
        {" "}
        <h1>{elem.name}</h1>
        <p />
      </li>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      {all_applications}
      <button onClick={this.onFavorite}>Favorite</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. You should explain what error you get if you want people to help you in an effective way.

Comment: So you want a a "Favourite" button for each applicant?

Comment: @DacreDenny yes

Comment: @JRUtily I am not getting any errors, I just dont know how to add it by the id(one-by-one)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach with a separate `Application` component. `onFavorite` method adds only the `id`s to the `saved` state. If the `id` is already there, it removes. `renderFavs` method maps the `saved` state then grab the related applications from the state.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    applications: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "John Smith",
        position: "Server",
        applied: "03/15/16",
        experience: 2,
        availability: {
          M: 2,
          T: 2,
          W: 1,
          Th: 2,
          F: 1,
          S: 0,
          Su: 0
        },
        questions: [
          {
            text: "Have you ever been convicted of a felony?",
            answer: "No"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Jane Smith",
        position: "Cook",
        applied: "02/08/16",
        experience: 4,
        availability: {
          M: 1,
          T: 1,
          W: 1,
          Th: 1,
          F: 0,
          S: 0,
          Su: 0
        },
        questions: [
          {
            text: "Have you ever been convicted of a felony?",
            answer: "Yes"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "David Jessup",
        position: "Chef",
        applied: "03/08/16",
        experience: 2,
        availability: {
          M: 2,
          T: 2,
          W: 2,
          Th: 2,
          F: 2,
          S: 0,
          Su: 0
        },
        questions: [
          {
            text: "Are you authorized to work in the United States?",
            answer: "Yes"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Clay vanSchalkwijk",
        position: "Cook",
        applied: "03/08/16",
        experience: 1,
        availability: {
          M: 1,
          T: 0,
          W: 1,
          Th: 0,
          F: 1,
          S: 0,
          Su: 0
        },
        questions: [
          {
            text: "Are you authorized to work in the United States?",
            answer: "Yes"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    saved: []
  };

  onFavorite = app => {
    const { saved } = this.state;
    const check = saved.includes(app.id);
    if (check) {
      const newSaved = saved.filter(fav => fav !== app.id);
      return this.setState({ saved: newSaved });
    }
    this.setState(currentState => ({
      saved: [...currentState.saved, app.id]
    }));
  };

  renderApplications() {
    const { applications } = this.state;
    return applications.map(app => (
      <Application key={app.id} app={app} onFavorite={this.onFavorite} />
    ));
  }

  renderFavs() {
    const { saved, applications } = this.state;
    const saveds = saved.map(id => applications.find(app => app.id === id));
    return saveds.map(fav => <p key={fav.id}>{fav.name}</p>);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{this.renderApplications()}</ul>
        <h3>Favorites</h3>
        {this.renderFavs()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Application = props => {
  const { app, onFavorite } = props;
  const handleFavorite = () => onFavorite(app);

  return <li onClick={handleFavorite}>{app.name}</li>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can render a "Favourite" button for each applicant, by making the following adjustment to your `render()` function:

```
render() {
    const all_applications = this.state.applications.map((elem) => {
      return(
        <li key={elem.id}> <h1>{elem.name}</h1>
          <p></p>
          { /* Render a favourite button for each 'elem' applicant. 
               Pass the elem/applicant data to the onFavorite method like so:
            */  }
          <button onClick={ () => this.onFavorite(elem) }>Favorite</button>
        </li>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Header />
      {all_applications}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an cannot read property of "onFavorite" of undefined error

Comment: @Berheet sorry about that , please see update above where you will need to use `.map((elem) => {` syntax - does this work for you?

Comment: that was right to get rid off error! But what would the function look like to add it to the array? right now i have:
onFavorite = () => {
        return(
            this.setState({
              saved:[...this.state.saved, savedApp]})
    
        )}

Comment: If you want to update onFavourite in that way, this should be possible:

`onFavorite = () => { 
    this.setState({ saved:[...this.state.saved, savedApp]}) 
}`

Would you like me to update the answer?